# How to stop a spool file from getting deleted?

Tags: ibm-midrange, spool

I have been assigned to study a series of CL programs. Collectively these programs perform some desired tasks. Some of them run in batch and the others run interactively. If any of them end up in error, DMPCLPGM statement is executed so that QPPGMDMP spool file is generated. Now due to some design flaw, when the programs are re-run after the failure QPPGMDMP is somehow deleted. This spool file is intended to be kept so that people can study the cause of the error later. As there are too many programs to check it is not so feasible to simply scan all the source members. My plan is to somehow lock the spool file, so that when it is about to be removed by a program it will cause that particular program to crush. How practical is this method? Or is there any other better way to back track the program responsible for deleting QPPGMDMP? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to determine what's happening to the spooled file is to enable security auditing with the [`CHGSECAUD`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzarl%2Frzarlchgsaud.htm) command and make sure auditing is enabled for `*SPLFDTA`.

You can then monitor spooled file activity with the [`DSPAUDJRNE ENTTYPE(SF)`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzarl%2Frzarlchgsaud.htm) command.

**More information:**

- [Using the security audit journal](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzarl%2Frzarlchgsaud.htm)
- [Analyzing audit journal entries with query or a program](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzarl%2Frzarlchgsaud.htm)

Comment: Any concrete examples regarding security auditing? The description on the IBM website is too abstract to follow.

Comment: It's just two steps as described in my answer. Enable spooled file auditing with the `CHGSECAUD` command; wait for the files to be deleted; check the audit log with the `DSPAUDJRNE` command.

Comment: Be **extremely** careful using CHGSECAUD. I'd suggest **only** using it when initially setting system audit behavior. Security/audit attributes can be too easily changed unintentionally. And it might be better to use the job accounting journal (QACGJRN) for this. Set system value QACGLVL to (*JOB *PRINT) and possibly better info can be seen than from the audit journal.

Answer (score 0):

You should figure out what is deleting them. Is is being printed? A `SAVE(*YES)` would fix that. Is it being deleted? Then you can't stop it. You need to fix the issue. I suppose another option to be to change the authority of the spool file to something the user running doesn't have the authority to delete.

While there could be other ways to delete spool files, usually `DLTSPLF` is the culprit.

You can use [this article](http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg011806-story03.html) to learn about changing authority.

Are you sure they are being deleted and just never created?

Comment: The spool won't get printed, that is for sure. How to change the authority of the spool file then? How many different ways are there to remove a spool file (given it is not to be printed)?

Comment: I am aware how to change object authority for general objects. Is it going to work in the same way for spool file as well? I have never tried this before.

Originally the spool file is in the status RDY. Then after re-run the programs it turns into FIN. As it is never printed I could only assume that it is deleted at some point. Any other possibilities?

Comment: I believe so. It is just an object.

Comment: If the spool file is generated by a batch job (under the current user), is it possible to change its authority as well? Do I need to specify library name then?

Comment: No, a spool file is not a first-class object at the OS level. It is not a member of a library, and cannot be used with general object commands, such as `DSPOBJD`, `RNMOBJ`, `MOVOBJ`, etc.  It is created in a job, also not a first-class object, and a completed job will continue to exist on the system until all its spool files are gone.  People sometimes confuse spool file with print files, which might perhaps be thought of as templates for the creation of spool files.